# Website caching (using DNS)

Tags: dns, cache

Some time ago I landed on a website that provided a paid service that caches websites. As I understood it, the only thing I needed to do was change the DNS record of my website and point it to them. Their service would check if my website is online and direct traffic to my server. In the event my server is unavailable they would provide a cached version.

I'm not talking about the free publicly available Google cache/archive.org or a *dumb* CDN solution.

The problem is that I can't remember which company provided this service.

Comment: What is a "dumb CDN solution"? What you describe is just a mirroring service combined with what sounds like a DNS failover. This is [far less desirable](http://serverfault.com/questions/60553/why-is-dns-failover-not-recommended) than proper loadbalancing methods, such as those used by CDNs.

Comment: By a "dumb" CDN solution I mean a CDN where I have to decide which files I need to copy and only static files are served.

Comment: Many CDN providers also provide full-site acceleration, but the solution you describe would end up just mirroring a cached copy of your site, so it would effectively be serving up all static content anyways. It's not proper load-balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was it https://www.cloudflare.com/ ?

Comment: That video on the homepage seems familiar. It's probably the site I was looking for.